# DataServiceQueryException timeout

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

As you can see I can I made the web service timeout, and I can catch the exception. But I want to catch the query timeout exception (DataServiceQueryException). Is this possible? What is the property? I have searched and cant find any solution.

```
 try
 {
     rms.Timeout = 1; //to make the timeout
     List = rms.Query.Where(d => d.TimeStamp != null && d.TimeStamp > StartDate && d.TimeStamp <= EndDate).ToList();
 }
 catch (DataServiceQueryException queryExp)
 {
      //I want to catch the query timeout exception
 }
 catch (WebException ex)
 {
     if (ex.Status == System.Net.WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Request Timeout");
        return false;
     }
```

}